# Load JSON error

Tags: c#, json, win-universal-app

I try to load json like this

```
private async Task<JsonValue> FetchAsync(string url)
{
    // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
    using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
            JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());

            // Return the JSON document:
            return jsonDoc;
        }
    }
}
```

but in this `JsonObject.Load(stream));`  I have error:

> Error CS0117  'JsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'Load'

As I read on MSDN JsonObject has Load method.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: [No, it doesn't](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: No it doesn't. JsonObject is part of Json.NET and *doesn't* have a load method, simply because it is *not* the class that serializes/deserializes data. Were you looking at [a different class perhaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject(v=vs.95).aspx) from a framework (Silverlight) that doesn't exist any more?

Comment: Why do you people are still using `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: hm. I use this code in Xamarin for Android and it works. Okay

How I can download JSON ?


I write UWP app @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev because all code in the end calls HttpWebRequest? For example, HttpClient uses HttpWebRequest internally

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And `HttpWebRequest` uses sockets internally. We can go even deeper, but we don't. Moreover, .NET Core version of `HttpClient` doesn't use `HttpWebRequest` anymore, but the WinHttp instead.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev Adding a fourth framework in this discussion is a bit over the top and not quite related

Comment: Mostly speculation but, `JsonValue` has a Load function. `JsonObject` has a Parse function which if you read your stream into text then use `JsonObject.Parse()` might have the desired effect.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is why people should use `HttpClient` and let Microsoft bother with frameworks for you.

Comment: I need to write it like this JsonObject.Parse(stream)? @Shelby115

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late for this post but maybe i can help somebody else.
You should add this line to your project:

```
using System.Json
```

Right-click on references and then click add reference. Check System.Json box and then click ok.